# Fetched Results Controller Not Updated When Main Context Saved

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using nested managed object contexts for core data saves.  I have a writerContext that writes changes to the persistent store and a mainContext that is a child of the writerContext.  The main context is used for my fetched results controller and other UI related tasks.  I then have a workerContext which is a child of the mainContext.  The workerContext is used for saves from a web service.

From everything I have read, changes from the workerContext should automatically propagate to the mainContext when the worker context is saved and then on to the writerContext when the mainContext is saved.  My data is getting saved to the store, so I know everything is propagating through the mainContext, but the changes are not seen by my fetched results controller. Does anyone know why my fetched results controller delegate would not be seeing the changes and updating the UI?

I posted the code below for the relevant parts of the core data stack.

```
    // Create Main Context 
    mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    mainContext.parentContext = writerContext
    mainContext.name="mainContext"
    //        mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    mainContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(mergeType:NSMergePolicyType.MergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType )

    func saveMainContext (mainContext:NSManagedObjectContext) {
    print("+++++++++++ \(__FUNCTION__)  ++++++++++++")
    mainContext.performBlockAndWait{ () -> Void in
        let wc=mainContext.updatedObjects

        print("1-Main thread\(NSThread.isMainThread())")
        print("mainContext.changedObjects=\(wc.count)")
        if mainContext.hasChanges {

            do {
                print("try")
                try mainContext.save()
                    self.saveWriterContext(mainContext.parentContext!)


            } catch let error as NSError {

                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                // Handle Error
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong!")
            }
        }
    }
}

func saveWriterContext (writerContext:NSManagedObjectContext) {
    print("+++++++++++ \(__FUNCTION__)  ++++++++++++")
    writerContext.performBlock{ () -> Void in
        let wc=writerContext.updatedObjects
        print("writerContext.changedObjects=\(wc.count)")
        if writerContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                print("try")
                try writerContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {

                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                // Handle Error
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong!")
            }
        }
    }
}

func saveWorkerContext(workerContext:NSManagedObjectContext) {
    print("+++++++++++ \(__FUNCTION__)  ++++++++++++")
    workerContext.performBlockAndWait{
        let wc=workerContext.updatedObjects
        print("workerContext.changedObjects=\(wc.count)")
        if workerContext.hasChanges {
            do {
                print("try")
                try workerContext.save()

                    self.saveMainContext(workerContext.parentContext!)

            } catch let error as NSError {

                NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                // Handle Error
            } catch {
                print("Something went wrong!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried merging changes in `contextDidSaveContext(notification: NSNotification)`

```
self.mainContext.mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification(notification)
```

Any help figuring out why the fetched results controller is not updating would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to implement ``NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`` and update table with it

Comment: I have implemented `NSFetchedResultsContollerDelegate` but it does not ever call `func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController)` or any other delegate methods.